# How to get pyright to use the current conda environment automatically?

Tags: conda, liskov-substitution-principle, mason, pyright

I would like pyright installed by [Mason](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim) to use the current conds environment, that is the one used when opening neovim.

If I put a **pyrightconfig.json** shown below in root dir of my project, this will work

```
{
    "venv": "some name",
    "venvPath": "/opt/miniconda3/envs/"
}
```

but this fixed an environment, I would like to use the one used in the session that opened neovim without having to write a **pyrightconfig.json**.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I tried your workaround, but that also did not work for me.

Comment: @MarianoKamp   I finally found out it is because tmux will mess up the $PATH, so if I left tmux everything works out just fine. Then what i did is to make $PATH inside tmux looks the same as outside tmux. Maybe this will help you too, but I am not sure. Good luck

Comment: I use tmux too. Interesting. Will investigate :) Thanks @H.Li.